# No evalua correctamente al número 4

Tags: c#, algoritmos

Tengo una función que me evalúa si un número es primo devolviendo un valor booleano.

En este condicional debí evaluar el 4 porque no lo evaluaba correctamente
===>  if (num == 0 || num == 1 || num == 4)

Esta es mi función, si quito el 4 del condicional me dice que es un numero primo, para los demás evalúa correctamente y deseo de que ese 4 no vaya en ese condicional.[image: Evalúa correctamente con el 4 rn rl condicional]
[image: Evalúa incorrecatente el 4 si se elimina el 4 del condicional]

```
//Método principal
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        int[] array = new int[10];
        int promedio = 0;
        array = CargarVector();
        promedio = PromedioVector(array);

        if (EsPrimo(promedio))
        {
            Console.Write("El promedio entero {0} de los número del vector es un número primo", promedio);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("El promedio entero {0} de los número del vector no es un número primo", promedio);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }



public static bool EsPrimo(int num)
        {
            bool primo = true;
            if (num == 0 || num == 1 || num == 4)
            {
                primo = false;
                return primo;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 2; i < (num / 2); i++)
                {
                    if ((num % i) == 0)
                    {
                        primo = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return primo;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola! puedes poner el código que manda llamar al método EsPrimo y el que imprime el resultado por favor.

Comment: Faltaba el igual, no necesito hacer todas las  comparaciones de los primos de un digito, no tiene sentido. El método EsPrimo() con la corrección planteada por Christian González es genérica y evalúa cualqier número entero. Evalúo el cero y el 1 en caso de que el usuario trate de romper el algoritmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambia la línea del for del método EsPrimo por `for (int i = 2; i <= (num / 2); i++)`

En el caso del 4 ocurre, con tu código, que el for evalua si 2<2, lo cual es falso y se pasa directo al return primo.

Answer (score 1):

Para optimizar un poco mas el código puedes hacer el `for` hasta la raiz del numero, o sea:

```
for (int i=2; i <= Math.Sqrt(i); i++ )
```